# How to support Map<String, Boolean> for rememberSaveable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Using the below

```
var state by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf(
        enumValues<NavigationItem>().associate { it.route to true }
    )
}

enum class NavigationItem(val route: String, val icon: Int) {
    Home("home", R.drawable.ic_home),
    Music("music", R.drawable.ic_music),
    Movies("movies", R.drawable.ic_movie),
    Books("books", R.drawable.ic_book),
    Profile("profile", R.drawable.ic_profile)
}
```

The `rememberSaveable` is not saving and restoring the state.

How can I have it save and restore?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it does save. But it has some bugs and is not restored in the right order. So make our own saver will help

```
var state by rememberSaveable(
    saver = mapSaver(
        save = { it.value },
        restore = { mutableStateOf(it as Map<String, Boolean>) }
    )
) {
    mutableStateOf(enumValues<NavigationItem>().associate {
        it.route to true
    })
}
```